# Unable to launch shadow-cljs with cider

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, shadow-cljs

I installed shadow-cljs as follows:

```
npm install -g shadow-cljs
```

Then I created a shadow-cljs.edn file, with the following:

```
[{:id "app"
                :source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "dev"]

                :figwheel {:on-jsload "myapp.system/reset"}

                :compiler {:main cljs.user
                           :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                           :output-to "dev-target/public/js/compiled/myapp.js"
                           :output-dir "dev-target/public/js/compiled/out"
                           :source-map-timestamp true
                           :preloads [devtools.preload]
                           :optimizations :none}}

               {:id "test"
                :source-paths ["src/cljs" "test/cljs" "src/cljc" "test/cljc"]
                :compiler {:output-to "dev-target/public/js/compiled/testable.js"
                           :main myapp.test-runner
                           :optimizations :none}}

               {:id "min"
                :source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc"]
                :jar true
                :compiler {:main myapp.system
                           :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/myapp.js"
                           :output-dir "target"
                           :source-map-timestamp true
                           :optimizations :advanced
                           :closure-defines {goog.DEBUG false}
                           :pretty-print false}}
               ]
```

Then in the already running clj repl, I do M-x cider-connect-sibling-cljs, and select the shadow  repl option. But I get that shadow-cljs Clojurescript REPL is not available. How do I get shadow cljs to work?

Comment: Your shadow-cljs.edn seems to be invalid. It should be a map and your builds should be under :builds. See more details in the shadow-cljs doc: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#target-browser